# Can't find a compatible marker cluster library to use with @Angular/google-maps; @types/googlemaps and @types/google.maps are incompatible

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

1/ Im using angular version 10
2/ I'm using the "GoogleMap" component shown here: 
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/google-maps/google-map/README.md
3/ the "GoogleMap" component wraps the google.maps.Map class from the Google Maps JavaScript API. it installs **@types/googlemaps**
4/ The Google maps JS API suggests using the @googlemaps/markerclusterer library for marker clustering. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering
5/ the markerclusterer library needs the **@types/google.maps** installed
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclusterer

6/ **@types/googlemaps installed in #3 is incompatible with @types/google.maps in #5**

Is there a markercluster library that someone can suggest that doesn't need @types/google.maps? Or perhaps A different way to go about this whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with yours, try to install `@angular/google-maps@11.2.13` but that package for `marker-clusterer` seems have bug/deprecated, I use that version and brings me warning messages in the browser said `google.maps.event.addDomListener() is deprecated`

Someone has raised issue for that but I didn't see how to fix that issue https://github.com/angular/components/issues/25255